# Pulling images from directory and making them smaller

Tags: php, image

Here is my code:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.smaller img{width:50px;}
</style>

<?php
include 'header.php'; 
   $files = glob("./photos/iphone5/*.*");
echo '<h2>iPhone 5 Images</h2>';
   for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
$image = $files[$i];
$info = pathinfo($image);
$file_name =  basename($image,'.'.$info['extension']);
echo '<a href="'.$image.'" target="_BALNK"><div class="smaller image"><img src="'.$image.'"</div></a>'."<br /><br />";
  }
   include 'footer.php'; 
 ?>
```

The problem is that sometimes it will load three images, sometimes it will load two, etc, also it loads them very slowly. What would you do different?

Basically what I want it to do is pull all images from a directory and then display them smaller, when the user clicks it then it takes them to the full image.

Comment: You should make thumbnail images as they are uploaded, show those when the user displays the page - then take them to the full image if they click on it.

Comment: Have a look at PHPThump, it's great for this kind of thing: http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I use ImageMagick: http://www.imagemagick.org

Comment: can you show me an example of how my file would look like with php thumb if you get what Im trying to do